# @include within a @foreach, keeps using the first elem of a collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Within a view I'm trying to @include a component like:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="col m4">
        {{$product -> model}}
        @include('components.thumb-product', ['model' => $product -> model])
    </div>
@endforeach
```

contents of components.thumb-product:

```
@extends('layouts.cards.thumb-product-a')
@section('model')
    {{$model}}
    {{$product -> model}}
@endsection
```

I have 5 different elements in $products, and with each iteration the @include('components.thumb-product') keeps outputting the first element.

However in @foreach, {{$product -> model}} (before the @include) outputs what I expect:

> DBTPI0PGC2, OWQE, TDH, 8WFXWRGL, C4M

@include('components.thumb-product'), {{$model}} & {{$product -> model}} outputs:

> DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2
>
> DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2, DBTPI0PGC2

I can't wrap my head around why this is the case, should I use something other, than @include?
Show me the way please.

Comment: You mean loop iterating same element 5 times ?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: $products[0] -> model = "foo",
$products[1] -> model = "foo2"
I expect getting "foo", then "foo2", so on .. from the loop. but I keep getting "foo" for each iteration.

Comment: what is the contents of `'layouts.cards.thumb-product-a')`

Comment: it's a simple div with the corresponding @yields. no typos, all tags have closing tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using @overwrite instead of @endsection in your components.thumb-product

```
@section('model')
    {{$model}}
    {{$product -> model}}
@overwrite
@extends('layouts.cards.thumb-product-a')
```

I had the same problem.